# Doubt about plurals in a sentence

Tags: phrases, grammatical-number, writing-style

I often find myself in this situation. I try to describe my time with something, but it doesn't come out sounding right to me.

Specifically, in this instance I'm trying to describe my time with someone. We had beers, we had multiple conversations over a few nights. This is what I came up with.

> We had great conversations over beers into the nights.

Is the above sentence grammatically correct? What about style? Why does it sound ugly to me if it is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no significant grammatical mistakes in your sentence. Maybe your sentence feels like a list to you? If you rearrange the parts, and try different arrangements of parts, maybe try some different verbs or nouns, you will be happy with is what fits your style.

You might say it like this:

> We spent a few evenings having great conversations over beer.
>
> For a few nights we drank beer and had great conversation well into the night.
>
> We had beer and great conversation over the course of a few nights.
>
> For a few nights, we talked and drank beer and had a wonderful time.
>
> It was great seeing him; we had wonderful conversations over beer for several nights.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is nothing wrong with the sentence. However, the last part and the usage of "beers" may be the cause of your problem. I suggest this rewrite:

> We spent few nights with great conversations over beer.

or

> For several nights, we had great conversations over beer.

I think using the singular beer will suffice

Answer (score 0):

*Beers* is incorrect. It's not the beer which is multiple but the bottles containing it. Consequently, it is *bottle* that should be pluralized:

> ...bottles of beer

Alternatively, keep *beer* singular and say:

> We had great conversations over beer into the nights.

Think of how you would use *water* in a sentence.

Comment: If you use *beer* in a countable sense, it is understood to mean units of beer: glasses, bottles, cans, etc., e.g. *How many beers does it take to get you drunk?* Moreover, *into the nights* is unlikely. An American, at least, could have conversation(s) over beer(s) *over the next few nights* or *into the night over the next few nights*, for example.

Comment: @choster I disagree and think Michael Massey has a good point. 'Beers' in the plural refers to different brews, in the same way that 'wines' refers not to individual glasses of wine but to different vintages. Strictly the same principle applies to coffee. We rely on context to tell us whether reference is to 'cups of coffee' or varieties of coffee. But as for beers, we in the UK would be more likely to say 'a few pints', as the imperial pint measure is the usual quantity served on tap from the bar.

Comment: @WS2 Perhaps that is the case in BrE, but in AmE it's entirely natural to pluralize some (by no means all) mass nouns to refer to their units of consumption. If asked to bring *a dozen sodas* for a party, I am not going to bring one can each of twelve varieties; and if I say I drank *six gin and tonics* at that party, I do not mean I sampled six different recipes; and so on and so on if I needed *fifty tissues* to clean up and *three coffees* with *three sugars* each to wake up after.

Comment: @choster None of yours differs too much from what we would say, except that with some drinks it seems we don't treat them as countable as readily as do you. 'Cans of beer, cans of fizzy', etc is the more usual way, with drink that is not pulled from the tap. Though there seem to be more countables among spirits, as in 'a few whiskies later he told us everything'. 'A few more martinis and she'll be dancing on the table'.